# SnakeYaml keep IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

As I tried to run the code from [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml) webiste, I keep getting the same error no matter what I do to try and resolve it. I've tried:

- Checking the name is correct and exists (dunno if it is a path problem, I'm directly referencing the file ("example.txt") in the input stream and the file is in the same package as the java file.
- Updating the libraries
- Putting the file name directly in yaml.load which just throws another exception (class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.lang.String and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'))
- Creating a new java project, same error.
- Find a solution on the internet.

```java
private void editConfig(String id) {
        
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
          .getClassLoader()
          .getResourceAsStream("config.yml");
        Map<String, Object> obj = yaml.load(inputStream);
        System.out.println(obj);
        
}
```

[image: Here is my file structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer;

Because the yaml file is in the same package as my class, I am supposed to get rid of the .getClassLoader.